# How to open website on division?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open a website in my division, but it does not seem to work.

Considering we have division `<div id='container'></div>`

We have `<a href='' onClick='dothis()'>Doit</a>`

And we have function

`function dothis({$("#container").html('<objectdata="http://www.google.sk"/>'); }`

Why doesn't this code open website to chosen division? (Source of jquery is included aswell)

Answer (score 2):

Google won't allow you to do this. Other syntax issues maybe?

Change `<objectdata...` to `<object data..`

Working example: http://runnable.com/VEK8Pt4rSBkGsuq3/jquery-object-data-test-for-javascript

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the capitalization in `onClick`
2. Put a space between `object` and `data`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that some websites don't allow you to open it in another `origin` and google is one of those.

Another is that you should use `<iframe src="">` tag for that purpose. (I'm not sure what `<objectdata>` is)

Comment: It does not seem to change anything.

Comment: Check your console as well. Function should be declared thise way: `function dothis(){  //your code here}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be,

function dothis({$("#container").html(''); }

After this is executed, an error will be thrown,

**Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY/SAMEORIGIN'**

because of the  X-Frame-Options option configured in the server for the HTTP response

The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a ,  or  . Sites can use this to avoid clickjacking attacks, by ensuring that their content is not embedded into other sites.